# Replicating integration results from a paper

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, integral

I’m reading Wacek’s paper [*Parameter Uncertainty in Loss Ratio Distributions and its Implications*](http://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/05fforum/05f165.pdf) and trying to figure out how to replicate some of the results.

Table 6, on page 190 of the paper, contains some results. Under Model B1, the density, $f_x(x|\theta)$, is assumed to be Normal with known $\mu = 0.7067$ and $\sigma=0.0745$. The formula of density is given by Eqn (2.3).
The pure premium is given by Eqn (5.1):

$$\int_R^{L+R} \! (x-R)f_x(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + L\int_{L+R}^\infty \! f_x(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

where L (Limit) = 0.5, and R (Retention) = 0.7.

According to the results provided in Table 6, after integrating, I'm supposed to get 2.02%, but what I'm getting is different. Here is the R code I'm using:

```
integrand1 <- function(x)
  {(x-0.7)*(1/(0.0745*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-0.7067)/0.0745)^2)}
l1 <- integrate(integrand1, lower = 0.7, upper = 0.75)

integrand2 <- function(x)
  {0.05*(1/(0.0745*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-0.7067)/0.0745)^2)}
l2 <- integrate(integrand2, lower = 0.75, upper = Inf)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried.

```
> mu <- 0.7067; s <- 0.0745;
> L <- 0.05; R <- 0.7;
> f <- function(x) dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=s)
> integrate( function(x) (x-R)*f(x), R, L+R)$value + L*integrate( f, L+R, Inf)$value;
[1] 0.02023684
```

Looks good. I leave it to you to debug your code... Oh! I see. There's some `0.745` instead of `0.0745`. You shouldn’t type several times the same constants. Using variables like I did with `mu`, `s` `L` and `R` is much safer. Also, using the predefined `dnorm` function for the density of the normal lowers the probability of typos...

Comment: Thank you, Elvis! I modified my code by correcting the value of sigma = 0.0745, and I got the same result. Thanks for the advice, I'll keep this in mind :-)